# Cant uploading data through foreign key with crispy forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am uploading a photo by using a foreign key in forms but I didn't get any data in a database and I didn't get any errors.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class username(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone=models.BigIntegerField()
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=100)
class Profilephoto(models.Model):
    profile_photo = models.FileField(upload_to='media/')
    uname = models.ForeignKey(username, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profilephoto
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profilephoto
        fields = ['profile_photo','uname']
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from .models import username,Profilephoto
from .form import DocumentForm
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        email = request.POST['email']
        username(name=name,phone=phone,email=email).save()
        users = username.objects.latest('id')
        return render(request, 'home.html',{'usernames': users})
    else:
        users = username.objects.latest('id')
        return render(request, 'home.html',{'usernames': users})
def data1(request,id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        obj = username.objects.get(id=id)
        form = DocumentForm(instance=obj)
        return render(request, 'data1.html', {'form': form, 'usernames': obj})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        obj = username.objects.get(id=id)
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        return render(request, 'data1.html', {'usernames': obj})
```

data1.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form|crispy }}
<div align="center">p
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Please Help me Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because your `DocumentForm` is form of model `Profilephoto` and in view function you are passing `Username`'s instance.

so in your `views.py`, try this:

```
def data1(request,id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        obj = username.objects.get(id=id)
        form = DocumentForm()
        return render(request, 'data1.html', {'form': form, 'usernames': obj})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        obj = username.objects.get(id=id)
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        return render(request, 'data1.html', {'usernames': obj})
```